# How to Load XML File Contents using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, xml, xmlhttprequest

I'm looking for a way to load an XML file's contents directly into a Javascript variable. Say I have the following directory structure:

```
/index.html
/loader.js
/file.xml
```

In `index.html`, there is a `<body>` tag, whose contents should be replaced with the contents of the XML file. So if the XML file contains:

```
<element>
    <item>Item One</item>
    <item>Item Two</item>
</element>
```

Then after the dynamic load, the HTML would be:

```
...
<body>
<element>
...
</element>
</body>
...
```

My question is, what function can I use in `loader.js` to load the contents straight into a variable? I have used XmlHttpRequests and the ActiveX XMLDOM parser, but all just give me a structural data model that I then have to sort through to find my elements. I don't need to parse anything, I just want to obtain all the file contents.

**Note:** HTML/Javascript only, no server-side code.

Comment: This can be combersome to do with plain-old JavaScript, are you using any frameworks? (before someone says "use jQuery"...)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think I may have figured it out. The following seems to work pretty well:

```
function loadFileToElement(filename, elementId)
{
    var xmlHTTP = new XMLHttpRequest();
    try
    {
    xmlHTTP.open("GET", filename, false);
    xmlHTTP.send(null);
    }
    catch (e) {
        window.alert("Unable to load the requested file.");
        return;
    }

    document.getElementById(elementId).innerHTML=xmlHTTP.responseText;
}
```

Comment: You might want to consider running this asynchronously.  Synchronous AJAX requests can lock up the browser's UI giving users in impression that their browser is hung.

Comment: This will be run from the client-side though, not on a server, so we're not too worried about the performance. Picture double-clicking an HTML file on your desktop.

Comment: I get CORS exception when I do this

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can read the responseText property of XmlHttpRequests to have the plain text before the parsing?